# Check a checkbox in bootstrap multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using boostrap multi select drop-down. On pageload i have two checkboxes checked in the drop-down list. I have added data-attributes for option values. On clicking a checkbox, if data-attribute value is greater than zero i need to kepp the checkbox checked. I have used jquery method to check a checkbox

```
$(".checkbox").prop("checked",true)
```

but when i check the number of checkboxes checked using `$(".checkbox option:selected)` it is not including the checkbox which i checked progrmatically. Can any one help me.

HTML generated for bootstrap multiselect drop-down:

```
<select class="form-control" id="comm" multiple="multiple" name="comm[]" style="display: none;">
<option value="abc" data-id="0">abc</option>
<option value="xyz" data-id="0">xyz</option>
<option value="pqr" data-id="0">pqr</option>
<option value="mno" selected="selected" data-id="24">mno</option>        
</select>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected">xyz</button>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="abc">abc</label>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="xyz"> xyz</label>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="pqr"> pqr</label>
      </a>
 </li>
 <li class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="mno"> mno</label>
      </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This only shows half of the problem.  Please include the code for the elements that this is acting on.  For example, `$(".checkbox")` will match elements with a `class="checkbox"`, but will **not** match `input` elements of `type="checkbox"`.  The actual problem could be a disparity in the element definition vs the jQuery (a common occurrence here on SO).  This is a necessity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".checkbox:checked")
```

Comment: Same result as i mentioned above

Comment: Post a sample html which is rendered in browser